# read and use table data to fill other table

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a file which has lines containing:

```
domainname.com data2 data3
domainname2.com data5 data6
```

I am trying to write a bash script which reads the file and puts it in a database.
But there are 2 tables which have to be filled. The first one is filled now and the second one needs the ID data from the first table to fill in the second. I've tried for hours now to run the second part (first table is filled now), but keep getting errors.
This is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile="mailertable4a.txt"
cat $inputfile | while read domain fwip user_id; do
##    echo "INSERT IGNORE INTO user_addresses (address,enabled,user_id,address_type,load_balance) VALUES ('$domain', '1', '$user_id', '1', '0');"
      counter=$("echo SELECT id FROM user_addresses WHERE user_addresses.address = '$domain';")
      echo "INSERT IGNORE INTO mail_hosts (address,enabled,port,useraddress_id) VALUES ('$fwip', '1', '25', '$counter');"
done | mysql -uroot -pmypasswd ******;
```

so the first table was filled with the ## line. In the next line I try to get the id number from that table and use it in line 3.
But i get the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'domainname.com';')' at line 1

I tried several things but keep getting errors.

Comment: Not sure if this is causing the problem, but `counter=$("echo SELECT ... = '$domain;")` is a weird way of assigning a value to a variable.  What is wrong with counter="SELECT ... = '$domain'"?  Actually, since variable `domain` is not exported, then the child process will not see it.

Comment: I tried that too, but got the same error: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'domainname.com'')' at line 1